# Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined but no issue in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

wassup Folks,

I got the following error from my component called "SearchReactTableContainer". I looked inside but everything looks well to many. Any Ideas how to fix this? I looked into the network conditions and the needed data from my resulting query is provided without any issues to my frontend.

SearchReactTableContainer.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { has, isNil } from "ramda";

import CockpitSearchInput from "@components/SearchInput";
import SearchReactTable from "@cockpitComponents/SearchReactTable";
import {
  MY_CASES_FILTER_KEY,
  UNASSIGNED_FILTER_KEY
} from "@modules/CaseManager/CaseManagerDashboard/constants";
import { Col, Row } from "antd";

// TODO: TO BE REMOVED
const pagesCount = 3855;

export default class SearchReactTableContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { limit, searchValue } = this.props;
    const orMyCases = localStorage.getItem(MY_CASES_FILTER_KEY);
    const orUnassignedCases = localStorage.getItem(UNASSIGNED_FILTER_KEY);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      searchValue: searchValue || "",
      data: [],
      pageSize: limit,
      pagesCount,
      orMyCases: this.parseNonNullValue(orMyCases),
      orUnassignedCases: this.parseNonNullValue(orUnassignedCases)
    };

    this.triggerFetchMore = this.triggerFetchMore.bind(this);
  }

  parseNonNullValue(value) {
    try {
      return !isNil(value) ? JSON.parse(value) : true;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
    }
  }

  async fetchMoreFromGraphql(fetchMore, variables, tableKey) {
    return await fetchMore({
      variables,
      updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult || !previousResult) return previousResult;
        if (!(tableKey in previousResult)) {
          return [];
        }
        return {
          ...previousResult,
          ...fetchMoreResult[tableKey]
        };
      }
    });
  }

  async onFetchDataHandler(state) {
    const { page, pageSize, sorted, filtered } = state;
    const { tableKey, fetchMore } = this.props;
    const { searchValue, orMyCases, orUnassignedCases } = this.state;
    this.changeTableLoadingState();
    const response = await this.fetchMoreFromGraphql(
      fetchMore,
      {
        searchValue,
        offset: page * pageSize,
        limit: pageSize,
        page,
        pageSize,
        sorted,
        filtered,
        filters: {
          orMyCases,
          orUnassignedCases
        }
      },
      tableKey
    );
    let { data } = response;
    const pagesCount =
      searchValue.length === 0
        ? has("totalCount", data[tableKey])
        ? Math.ceil(data[tableKey].totalCount / pageSize)
        : has("items", data[tableKey])
          ? Math.ceil(data[tableKey].items.length / pageSize)
          : Math.ceil(data[tableKey].length / pageSize)
        : this.state.pagesCount;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      loading: false,
      data: data[tableKey].items ? data[tableKey].items : data[tableKey],
      pageIndex: page,
      pageSize,
      pagesCount
    });
  }

  async triggerFetchMore(searchValue = "") {
    const { tableKey, fetchMore, tableName } = this.props;
    const { orMyCases, orUnassignedCases } = this.state;
    this.changeTableLoadingState();
    const variables = {
      searchValue,
      offset: 0,
      limit: this.state.pageSize,
      filters: {
        orMyCases,
        orUnassignedCases
      }
    };
    const response = await this.fetchMoreFromGraphql(fetchMore, variables, tableKey);
    const { data } = response;
    try {
      await this.setState(prevState => {
        const { pageSize } = prevState;
        const pagesCount =
          searchValue.length === 0
            ? has("totalCount", data[tableKey])
            ? Math.ceil(data[tableKey].totalCount / pageSize)
            : has("items", data[tableKey])
              ? Math.ceil(data[tableKey].items.length / pageSize)
              : Math.ceil(data[tableKey].length / pageSize)
            : this.state.pagesCount;
        prevState = {
          ...prevState,
          loading: false,
          data: data[tableKey].items ? data[tableKey].items : data[tableKey],
          searchValue,
          pagesCount
        };
        return prevState;
      });
      localStorage.setItem(`${tableName}.searchValue`, searchValue);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  changeTableLoadingState() {
    this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      columns,
      dataFormatter,
      search = true,
      defaultSorted,
      filterBlock
    } = this.props;
    const { data, pagesCount, pagesSize, loading, searchValue } = this.state;
    let formattedData = data;
    if (typeof dataFormatter === "function") {
      formattedData = dataFormatter(data);
    }
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {search && (
          <Row>
            <Col span={6}>
              <CockpitSearchInput
                onChange={this.triggerFetchMore}
                initialValue={searchValue}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        )}
        {!isNil(filterBlock) && filterBlock(this)}
        <SearchReactTable
          {...this.props}
          manual
          data={formattedData}
          columns={columns}
          loading={loading}
          // Request new data when things change
          onFetchData={(state, instance) => this.onFetchDataHandler(state, instance)}
          pages={pagesCount} // Display the total number of pages
          pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]}
          defaultPageSize={pagesSize}
          className="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
          defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
        />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I'll add a screenshot showing me the actual issue in the developer tab.

[Component that uses SearchReactTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUdSh.png)

Comment: seems like the issue is from `SelectReactTable` component. Are you using a monolith architecture or that package is from npm registry?

Comment: Are you using webpack? if yes, make sure the configuration is correct. Looks like React is not getting loaded/resolved.

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá Ye, monolith architecture.But I import it normally from the react lib.

Comment: @Sujith That's the only page where I get this component error, alltough other areas also use a react comp. without any issue. However, I can show u my config, if neccessarry.